# Kill Subprocess from GUI Button " Not Defined "

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import _thread



gui = Tk()

gui.geometry("+350+350")
gui.resizable(0,0)

gui.title(" * ---  Comm Test  --- * ")

class CreateButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,buttonName="", buttonName2 = "" ,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.folderPath = StringVar()
        self.btnFind2 = ttk.Button(self,text = buttonName,command=do_sth)
        self.btnFind2.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20 , pady = 10)
        self.btnQuit = ttk.Button(self,text = buttonName2,command=kill_comm)
        self.btnQuit.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=20 , pady = 10)

def do_sth():
    _thread.start_new_thread(comm_func, ())

def comm_func():
    cmd_specs = ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', "C:\\PS\\TST.PS1"]
    proc_tst = subprocess.Popen(cmd_specs , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)

def kill_comm():
    proc_tst.kill()

btn1 = CreateButton(gui," START " , " KILL ")
btn1.grid(row=4)
gui.mainloop()
gui.destroy()
```

I am using _thread because my GUI was freezing. 
But the problem is that after I call the subprocess ( and this part works ), when I try to hit the button " KILL ", it returns :

> NameError: name 'proc_tst' is not defined

I've been struggling with this for a while already, but didn't manage to solve this.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with variable scoping. In Python - and in most programming languages - variables defined in a particular function are not available to other functions or in the main function. This is the 'local' scope.

You define `proc_tst` inside the function `comm_func`, so when you reference this variable in `kill_comm()`, there is no variable 'to be found'.

You could obviously use global variables, however that is probably not what you want to do.
You could instead define the functions inside the class `CreateButton`, but I will preface this with saying that this design is quite strange, as classes usually represent an 'object' or 'structure'. Nethertheless, the following code 'works':

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import _thread



gui = Tk()

gui.geometry("+350+350")
gui.resizable(0,0)

gui.title(" * ---  Comm Test  --- * ")

class CreateButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,buttonName="", buttonName2 = "" ,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=parent,**kw)
        self.folderPath = StringVar()
        self.btnFind2 = ttk.Button(self,text = buttonName,command=self.do_sth)
        self.btnFind2.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=20 , pady = 10)
        self.btnQuit = ttk.Button(self,text = buttonName2,command=self.kill_comm)
        self.btnQuit.grid(row=4,column=2,padx=20 , pady = 10)
    def comm_func(self):
        cmd_specs = ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', "C:\\PS\\TST.PS1"]
        self.proc_tst = subprocess.Popen(cmd_specs , stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines = True)
    def kill_comm(self):
        self.proc_tst.kill()
    def do_sth(self):
        _thread.start_new_thread(self.comm_func, ())


btn1 = CreateButton(gui," START " , " KILL ")
btn1.grid(row=4)
gui.mainloop()
gui.destroy()
```